# C++ Call functions based on enum values

Tags: c++, templates

I have this code

```
class Foo {

private:

    enum class Heuristic {
        ONE,
        TWO,
        THREE
    };

    Heuristic h;

    void select();

};


void Foo::select() {
    if (h == Heuristic::ONE)
        selectONE();
    else if (h == Heuristic::TWO)
        selectTWO();
    else
        selectTHREE();
}

void selectONE() {};
void selectTWO() {};
void selectTHREE() {};
```

Based on the value of `heuristic` I want to call a specific function in `select()`. I don't know the value of `heuristic` at compile time, as it depends on user input. To avoid the conditional check in `select()` I would like to use templates. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Why don't you want conditions checks? What's wrong with them? If you don't know it at compile time, there s no performance improvement or so.

Comment: You can't avoid checking the value, but you can use a `switch` statement instead which the compiler can potentially optimize better via jump table.

Comment: @Mgetz By using a lookup array you _can_ avoid checking the value. It becomes a simple pointer arithmetic addition instead, so there is no branching and it's probably as fast as it can get.

Comment: @TedLyngmo that's basically what a jump table is, but it doesn't require construction.

Comment: @Mgetz True - the best thing for speed would probably be to avoid that completely and to just store the the selected function in a function pointer.

Comment: @TedLyngmo see my suggestion on the selected answer for a v-table option. Which is de-facto that. But at the end of the day the OP needs to profile. Honestly? This is probably not actually hurting performance because this sort of thing almost any modern processor is really good at doing branch prediction for.

Comment: @Mgetz Sure, a vtable-based solution would probably be even nicer. No messy lookups visible in the code either. I'd voted for that answer if it had popped up :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To avoid the conditional check in `select()` [...]

A simple way to avoid all conditional checks (hidden or otherwise) in `select()` could be to create an array of pointers to your functions. You then look the function up by using its current `Heuristic` value (which must start at 0 and not have any gaps). If the `Heuristic` value changes rarely, you can even move the lookup out of `select()` completely.

Example:

```
##include <iostream>

void selectONE() { std::cout << "one\n"; };
void selectTWO() { std::cout << "two\n"; };
void selectTHREE() { std::cout << "three\n"; };

using func_ptr_t = void(*)(); // the signature of your functions

class Foo {
public:
    enum class Heuristic {
        ONE,
        TWO,
        THREE
    };

    void set_heuristic(Heuristic); // a function to do the lookup
    void select();

private:
    Heuristic h;
    func_ptr_t current_func;       // a  pointer to the selected function 
};

void Foo::set_heuristic(Heuristic value) {
    // a simple map from Heuristic value to function pointer
    static const func_ptr_t funcmap[] = {
        &selectONE,
        &selectTWO,
        &selectTHREE,
    };

    h = value; // perhaps not needed?

    // look up the function pointer based on "h"
    current_func = funcmap[static_cast<unsigned>(h)];
}

void Foo::select() {
    // a pretty fast callsite:
    current_func();
}

int main() {
    Foo bar;
    bar.set_heuristic(Foo::Heuristic::ONE);
    bar.select();   // prints "one"
}
```

Comment: Doesn't a static function variable give some additional runtime costs? A static member of the class would be my first choice.

Comment: @super It costs when it's first used. Nothing after that if I'm not mistaken. If it's not used, it won't cost anything.

Comment: The cost of a static inside a function can be high, though, since it has to be initialized in a thread safe manner (i.e. it has to lock a mutex). It would be much better to initialize that table at compile time. If you want to protect it, use an unnamed namespace.

Comment: @AlexisWilke Yes, if this was a threaded program, it'd probably be cheaper to make the initialization of the map outside the function.

Answer (score 4):

As it depends on runtime values there is no way to get rid of some sort of runtime checks. Which are either done by you with `if`, `switch`, … or by a container like `std::map`, `std::unordered_map`

Due to that, your concern there should be readability and maintainability.

I would - like already suggested in a comment - use `switch` instead of `if`, but not because the compiler can optimize it better (IMHO the compiler will be able to generate the same code for both), but to allow the static analyzer to warn you about not used enums.

If the question is about performance concerns, then this should only be a problem if you call these functions at a high frequency. So if this is the case you could create a template-based entry point to your task, to which you pass the function as template argument based on the user selection:

```
template<auto SelectedHeuristic>
void Foo::task() {
   for( /* … */ ) {
      SelectedHeuristic();
   }
}

void Foo::select() {
    switch(h) {
       case Heuristic::ONE:
          Foo::task<selectONE>();
          break;
       case Heuristic::TWO:
          Foo::task<selectTWO>();
          break;
       case Heuristic::THREE:
          Foo::task<selectTHREE>();
          break;
    }
}

void selectONE() {};
void selectTWO() {};
void selectTHREE() {};
```

Comment: Yes, this question is mainly about performance concerns. I'm writing a SAT solver for a university class, so speed is all that matters. The literal selection heuristic is chosen by the user, but it doesn't change throughout the execution of the program. That's why I wanted to avoid a if or switch statement, as this function will be executed very frequently and the heuristic doesn't change anyways.

Comment: @philhimself In that case you would make the entry point to your solver template-based, and pass the heuristic to it as template argument, based on the user selection.

Comment: @philhimself it seems you're asking a bit of an X/Y problem question then. As what it sounds like you really need to do is find a way to cache these decisions after the user has made them. v-tables aren't a bad way to do it etc. But honestly, I'd profile before I try to micro-optimize anyway

Comment: @philhimself the `auto` in `template<auto SelectedHeuristic>` is a c++17 feature which might be important to know.

Comment: vtable can be a problem (depending on what those functions do) with respect to optimization/inlining. But there might not be a big difference between the `if`/`switch` version and the template-based version. But yes there the only way to figure that out is profiling @Mgetz

Answer (score 0):

define a `map<Heuristic, lambdas>` where the lambdas are defined as
void and taking no parameters

```
void f()
```

then take the user input and get the value of that input key and trigger the lambda

Comment: I recommend unordered_map, which has O(k) access, not O(log(n))

Comment: This doesn't really get rid of the compare, it just hides it and potentially creates other issues if they add more values later. Wouldn't a `switch` be a better answer?

Comment: in a map you dont have to compare @Mgetz

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ "_in a map you dont have to compare_" - Not for equality, but `operator<` is used to compare the keys.

Comment: *You* don't but the map is doing compares, so it doesn't actually remove that. It also has the issues with default values (or lack there of).

Comment: ... probably making code unnecessary complex. I think it's better to help the OP realize that nothing is wrong with a conditional statement.

Comment: how the map finds a given key is hidden for the developer and that is the sense of avoiding the explicitly compare operation

Comment: I think the difference only make sense for a big enum. For 3 values, simple `switch` is simple, elegant and better. If the enum would be bigger, then an `unordered_map` start to be faster. Not sure however if the OP needs efficiency.